# Have in Grid.js a option of "inline edit" cell values?

Tags: gridjs

Have in Grid.js an option of "inline edit" cell values or possibility/plugin to implements them?

Like this:

- http://tabulator.info/examples/4.9#editable
- https://editor.datatables.net/

Comment: Someone? It's possible uses GRID.JS for data live/inline edit?

Comment: I'd like to know this as well ...

Answer (score 2):

You can add the `"contenteditable" : "true"` attribute (part of HTML 5) to your column definition:

```
new gridjs.Grid({
columns: [
    { id: 'name',
        name: 'Name',
        sort: false,
        attributes:{ 
            "contenteditable" : "true"
        }
    },
    { id: 'email',
        name: 'Email',
        sort: false 
    },
    ...
```

You can then add a listener (with vanilla JavaScript or whatever framework you're using) for the "input" event - which will fire when the data changes.